# In which order multiple abstract models are processed in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, abstract-class

So I have this structure where I have multiple abstract Django models and all my models inherit one or more of these abstract models, for instance

```
class BaseProblem(Base, Slugged, Ownable, Tagged)
```

Now a situation has so arisen that I need to make another abstract class which derives from all these classes and in that I have to write a save function that uses one of the field which is defined in the other abstract classes

```
class Slugged(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    title = models.CharField()
    slug = models.SlugField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # generate slug

class BaseProblem(Base, Slugged, Ownable, Tagged):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            # do something with slug field
```

But the issue is that when the save function for the XYZ class is executed, the slug field does not exist, because the slug field is not yet generated.

I am assuming the save function for abstract classes are being executed in alphabetical order that's why the slug field does not exist at the time the save function for `BaseProblem` is executed

Comment: As mentioned in the duplicate, this blog is a good read: http://python-history.blogspot.nl/2010/06/method-resolution-order.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, when I was googling I did not frame my query properly